# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, telebot

Почему при одном и том же значении выводит разные ответы.
В одном выводит нормально, а при другом выдаёт ошибку

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 2896 and this is thread id 15080.
```

Хотя значения одинаковые.

```
def joinIn(message):
    user = db.Select(message.text)
    if user is None:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Not exists")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, user)
        global id_user
        id_user = user[0]


@bot.message_handler(commands=['get'])
def get(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, id_user)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['MyBilcoins'])
def MyBilcoins(message):
    global id_user
    if id_user == None:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"You're didn't join!")
    else:
        s=db.SelsectCoins(id_user)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Your Bilcoins are " + str(s))

def Select(idd: str):
    conn= _connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?""",[int(idd)])
    return cursor.fetchone()

def SelsectCoins(idd: int):
    conn = _connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT coin FROM users WHERE id = ?""", [idd])
    return cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Это база данных.

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы подключаетесь к базе данных, добавьте следующее.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('your.db', check_same_thread=False)
```

Comment: Это ответ на собственный вопрос?